# Understanding the Chow-Rashevsky Theorem

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to understand the Chow-Rashevsky Theorem. I unfortunately do not have a formal knowledge of what's going on but have figured out most of the terms.

Basically a system $\Sigma$ must satisfy the Chow condition:

$$\mathtt{Lie}(X_1, \ldots, X_m)(q) = T_qM, \hspace{1em} \forall q\in M. $$

where $M$ is a manifold. But I cannot find a definition for $T_q$.

I think it is a linear transformation. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling extensively led me to this - apparently $T_q$ is the tangent space of the manifold.

More details [here](http://www.math.ku.dk/kurser/2006-07/blok3/geom2/notes/Chapter3.pdf/).

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is the tangent space. The condition means that although the number of vectors may be less than that of the ambient space, along with their iterated brackets they do span the whole space, i.e. the brackets contribute enough linearly independent vectors to make up.